# Get the id and pass that on UI Modal in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have used the following code to load a view in Jquery Ui dialog Modal.

Javsscript code to open Modal:

```
<script>
       $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
        $(function() {
            $( "#dialog_1" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                show: "blind",
                hide: "explode",
                height: 350,
                width: 450,
                modal: true
            });

            $('.loginForm').click(function(){               
                $('#dialog_1').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });     
        });
</script>
```

Onclick of this Open Dialog:

```
<a class="loginForm" href=""  id="<?php echo $info['clf_id'];?>">
   <?php echo $info['clf_title'];?>
</a>
```

**Here is div to load on Modal in which i load view:**
here is i am getting problem i have pass the `$id` in the function `classified_details($id);`.
This id is actual id of above  `<a>`tag.
how can i do this in my code or should use another way???

```
<div id="dialog_1">
 <?php
    $data['classfied_details'] = $this->classified_model->classified_details($id);
    $this->load->view('classified_datail', $data);
   ?>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the return of `$this->classified_model->classified_details($id)` ? and do you know that you can use `id` only once for one tag?

Comment: @Charlie:it will return array.for id its my mistake see edited code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to this would be to use ajax call to fill the dialog with proper data and then show it.

JS would be something like this. You call some action in your controller

```
$('.loginForm').click(function(){    
     $.ajax({
         url: '/controller/action',
         data: { id: $(this).attr('id)},
         dataType: 'html',
         type: 'POST',
         success: function(data){
             $('#dialog_1').html(data);
             $('#dialog_1').dialog('open');     
         }
    });  
});
```

In your action you just simply grab the passed id and call model function.

```
$data['classfied_details'] = $this->classified_model->classified_details($_POST['id']);
$this->load->view('classified_datail', $data);
```

You should'n use id attribute twice in a link. Try something like this:

```
<a class="loginForm" href="#" id="<?php echo $info['clf_id'];?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this: `$this->classified_model->classified_details($id);` is return array `$info`, you need this `ECHO:`

```
<a class="loginForm" href=""  id="<?php echo $classfied_details['info']['clf_id'];?>">
  <?php echo $classfied_details['info']['clf_title'];?>
</a>
```